# Crud operation "Delete" don't works in my first project in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm implementing in my first project the crud operation "delete", but the system take the command as a "get", whitout errors.

this is the controller:

```
class MoviesController < ApplicationController

def index
    @movies = Movie.all      
end
#GET /movies/:id
def show
    id = params[:id]
    @movie = Movie.find(id)
    #render plain: 'show'+params[:id]
end
#POST /movies/
# skip_before_action :verify_autenticity_token:
def create
    @movie = Movie.create!(params[:movie].permit(:title, :rating, :description, :realease_date))
    flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} was successfully created."
    redirect_to movies_path
end

#new
def new
end

def edit
  id = params[:id]
    @movie = Movie.find(id)
end

def update
  id = params[:id]
  @movie = Movie.find(id)
  if @movie.update_attributes!(params[:movie].permit(:title,:rating,:realease_date))   
   flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} has been edited."
   redirect_to movies_path
  end
end

def destroy
  id = params[:id]
  @movie = Movie.find(id)
  @movie.destroy
  flash[:notice] = "#{@movie.title} has been deleted."
  redirect_to movies_path
end


end
```

this is the view where is possible call "Delete" operation:

```
%h2 Details about #{@movie.title}

%ul#details
    %li
        Rating:
        = @movie.rating
    %li
        Released on:
        = @movie.realease_date#.strftime("%B %d, %Y")

%h3 Description:

%p#description= @movie.description

%h4 Reviews:

- if @movie.reviews.empty?
    %p
        No reviews for this movie...

-else 
    - @movie.reviews.each do |r|
        - u = Moviegoer.find(r.moviegoer_id)
        <b>#{r.vote}</b> (<i>#{Moviegoer.find(r.moviegoer_id).name}</i>) #{r.message} <br />


= link_to 'Add review', new_movie_review_path(@movie)
<br/><br/>



#{link_to 'Edit info', edit_movie_path(@movie)} - #{link_to 'Delete', movie_path(@movie), :method => :delete} - #{link_to 'Back to movie list', movies_path}
```

The problem probably is in the last line, because in server command line "Delete" isn't calls.
this is the server response (is the last GET that is execute when i press "Delete" on the browser) :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TNZYU.png)

file routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do

resources :movies do
    resources :reviews, only: [:new, :create, :destroy]
end
resources :moviegoers

root :to  => redirect('/movies')

end
```

Result of command "rake routes":

```
Prefix Verb   URI Pattern                                                                              Controller#Action
        movie_reviews POST   /movies/:movie_id/reviews(.:format)                                                      reviews#create
     new_movie_review GET    /movies/:movie_id/reviews/new(.:format)                                                  reviews#new
         movie_review DELETE /movies/:movie_id/reviews/:id(.:format)                                                  reviews#destroy
               movies GET    /movies(.:format)                                                                        movies#index
                      POST   /movies(.:format)                                                                        movies#create
            new_movie GET    /movies/new(.:format)                                                                    movies#new
           edit_movie GET    /movies/:id/edit(.:format)                                                               movies#edit
                movie GET    /movies/:id(.:format)                                                                    movies#show
                      PATCH  /movies/:id(.:format)                                                                    movies#update
                      PUT    /movies/:id(.:format)                                                                    movies#update
                      DELETE /movies/:id(.:format)                                                                    movies#destroy
           moviegoers GET    /moviegoers(.:format)                                                                    moviegoers#index
                      POST   /moviegoers(.:format)                                                                    moviegoers#create
        new_moviegoer GET    /moviegoers/new(.:format)                                                                moviegoers#new
       edit_moviegoer GET    /moviegoers/:id/edit(.:format)                                                           moviegoers#edit
            moviegoer GET    /moviegoers/:id(.:format)                                                                moviegoers#show
                      PATCH  /moviegoers/:id(.:format)                                                                moviegoers#update
                      PUT    /moviegoers/:id(.:format)                                                                moviegoers#update
                      DELETE /moviegoers/:id(.:format)                                                                moviegoers#destroy
                 root GET    /                                                                                        redirect(301, /movies)
   rails_service_blob GET    /rails/active_storage/blobs/:signed_id             /*filename(.:format)                               active_storage/blobs#show
rails_blob_representation GET    /rails/active_storage/representations/:signed_blob_id/:variation_key/*filename(.:format)    active_storage/representations#show
      rails_disk_service GET    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_key/*filename(.:format)                              active_storage/disk#show
 update_rails_disk_service PUT    /rails/active_storage/disk/:encoded_token(.:format)                                         active_storage/disk#update
      rails_direct_uploads POST   /rails/active_storage /direct_uploads(.:format)                                            active_storage/direct_uploads#create
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's hard to say exactly what's going on without seeing the corresponding routes. You might try running `rake routes` to see what the available routes are.

Based on the comments in your controller, I'm guessing you probably have to do something like pluralize the path `link_to 'Delete', movies_path(id: @movie.id), method: :delete`, but that would only fix the problem if your resource routes are misconfigured.

In order for the link to work as you have it configured your route file would either have to contain `resources :movies`, or a specially configured route to map to the delete action.

Comment: I have update file "routes.rb" and  answer of command "rake routes", can help you for the answer?

Comment: Try `{link_to 'Delete', "/movie/#{@movie.id}", :method => :delete}`. If that works, then something is going on with the route helper. Also, do you have any JavaScript on that page? You might be firing a `GET` request on a link click.